# Am I handling Location Updates Incorrectly?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

Currently my location code is all part of a singleton.  I am curious if this is what is causing my problems.  I am using the location singleton as part of both geofence regions and iBeacons.  I have multiple iBeacons in the location I am testing and it seems that sometimes a enter of a beacon region interrupts the exit of a previous region.  I am curious if this is happening because this is a singleton and if I should change this to a standard class that the app delegate initializes to start the monitoring and the app will handle the calls backs for each call back that occurs.  I think that since it is a singleton the second call back that occurs is stopping the first call back if it hasn't completed.

You can see from the log below that I exited the basement and it started a timed event to make sure I truly exited the basement (software filter to get rid of the rapid exit/enter that occurs with iBeacons).  Then I walked into my living room which fired another region event but we never get the message didExitRegion: Basement logged out.

```
2014-04-25 15:35:22.757 [2761:707] Just Requested Background Time
2014-04-25 15:35:22.761 [2761:707] Basement
2014-04-25 15:35:22.767 [2761:707] Start Timed Event To See If Its A False Exit
2014-04-25 15:35:22.777 [2761:707] Just Requested Background Time
2014-04-25 15:35:22.778 [2761:707] Basement
2014-04-25 15:35:22.780 [2761:707] Start Timed Event To See If Its A False Exit
2014-04-25 15:35:23.751 [2761:707] Just Requested Background Time
2014-04-25 15:35:23.753 [2761:707] didEnterRegion: Living Room
2014-04-25 15:35:23.772 [2761:707] Just Requested Background Time
2014-04-25 15:35:23.774 [2761:707] didEnterRegion: Living Room
2014-04-25 15:35:24.270 [2761:707] Job ID Value
2014-04-25 15:35:24.272 [2761:707] 3208
```

New log after changes made to nstimer:

```
2014-04-25 17:13:06.873 [3243:707] Just Requested Background Time
2014-04-25 17:13:06.875 [3243:707] Kitchen
2014-04-25 17:13:06.877 [3243:707] Start Timed Event To See If Its A False Exit
2014-04-25 17:13:06.884 [3243:707] Just Requested Background Time
2014-04-25 17:13:06.885 [3243:707] Kitchen
2014-04-25 17:13:06.886 [3243:707] Start Timed Event To See If Its A False Exit
2014-04-25 17:13:09.146 [3243:707] didExitRegion Basement
2014-04-25 17:13:09.149 [3243:707] Cancelled Exit Of Region: Basement
2014-04-25 17:13:09.881 [3243:707] Job ID Value
2014-04-25 17:13:09.883 [3243:707] 4040
2014-04-25 17:13:09.884 [3243:707] Connection Successful 
2014-04-25 17:13:10.878 [3243:707] Cancelled Exit Of Region: Kitchen
2014-04-25 17:13:10.889 [3243:707] Cancelled Exit Of Region: Kitchen
```

Code Updated:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    currentRegion = region;
    GeofenceObject *gObject = [[GeofenceObject alloc] init];
    gObject = [self getObjectForGeofence:region];

    //stop multiple notification deliveries
    if (notificationDelivered && ![gObject getIsBeacon])
    {
        notificationDelivered = NO;
        return;
    }

    BOOL alwaysNotify = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"alwaysNotifyLocation"];
    if (![self checkWifi] && ![self checkWWLAN] && ![gObject getIsBeacon])
    {
        [self notifyNoNetwork:gObject forState:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        return;
    }

    if ((alwaysNotify && ![gObject getIsBeacon]))
    {
        [self notifyAlways:gObject forState:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
        return;
    }

    BOOL isInBackground = NO;
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
    {
        isInBackground = YES;
    }

    NSTimer *timer = (NSTimer *)[self.timers objectForKey:[gObject getGeofenceName]];
    if (timer != nil)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self.timers removeObjectForKey:[gObject getGeofenceName]];
    }

    if (isInBackground && [gObject getIsBeacon])
    {
        [self beginBackgroundTask];
        NSLog(@"%@", [@"didEnterRegion: " stringByAppendingString:[gObject getGeofenceName]]);
        [self didEnterRegion:region forObject:gObject];
        return;
    }

    if (isInBackground)
    {
        [self beginBackgroundTask];
        NSLog(@"%@",[@"didEnterRegion " stringByAppendingString:[gObject getGeofenceName]]);
        [self didEnterRegion:region forObject:gObject];
        return;
    }

    if ([gObject getIsBeacon])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [@"didEnterRegion: " stringByAppendingString:[gObject getGeofenceName]]);
        [self didEnterRegion:region forObject:gObject];
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",[@"didEnterRegion " stringByAppendingString:[gObject getGeofenceName]]);
    [self didEnterRegion:region forObject:gObject];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    currentRegion = region;
    GeofenceObject *gObject = [[GeofenceObject alloc] init];
    gObject = [self getObjectForGeofence:region];

    //stop multiple notification deliveries
    if (notificationDelivered && ![gObject getIsBeacon])
    {
        notificationDelivered = NO;
        return;
    }

    BOOL alwaysNotify = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"alwaysNotifyLocation"];
    if (![self checkWifi] && ![self checkWWLAN] && ![gObject getIsBeacon])
    {
        [self notifyNoNetwork:gObject forState:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        return;
    }

    if ((alwaysNotify && ![gObject getIsBeacon]))
    {
        [self notifyAlways:gObject forState:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
        return;
    }

    BOOL isInBackground = NO;
    if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground)
    {
        isInBackground = YES;
    }

    if (isInBackground && [gObject getIsBeacon])
    {
        [self beginBackgroundTask];
        [gObject setJustExitedRegion:YES];
        [self replaceObjectWithUpdate:gObject];
        NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:region forKey:@"region"];
        NSLog(@"%@", [gObject getGeofenceName]);
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Start Timed Event To See If Its A False Exit");
        [self.timers setObject:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(checkBackOnExit:) userInfo:info repeats:NO] forKey:[gObject getGeofenceName]];
        return;
    }

    if (isInBackground)
    {
        [self beginBackgroundTask];
        NSLog(@"%@",[@"didExitRegion " stringByAppendingString:[gObject getGeofenceName]]);
        [self didExitRegion:region forObject:gObject];
        return;
    }

    if ([gObject getIsBeacon])
    {
        [gObject setJustExitedRegion:YES];
        [self replaceObjectWithUpdate:gObject];
        NSDictionary *info = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:region forKey:@"region"];
        NSLog(@"%@", [gObject getGeofenceName]);
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Start Timed Event To See If Its A False Exit");
        [self.timers setObject:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(checkBackOnExit:) userInfo:info repeats:NO] forKey:[gObject getGeofenceName]];
        return;
    }

    NSLog(@"%@",[@"didExitRegion " stringByAppendingString:[gObject getGeofenceName]]);
    [self didExitRegion:region forObject:gObject];
}

- (void)beginBackgroundTask
{
    NSLog(@"%@", @"Just Requested Background Time");
    bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        NSLog(@"%@", @"Just Cancelled Background Time");
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }];
}

- (void)checkBackOnExit:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    NSDictionary *info = [timer userInfo];
    CLRegion *region = [info objectForKey:@"region"];
    GeofenceObject *gObject = [[GeofenceObject alloc] init];
    gObject = [self getObjectForGeofence:region];
    if ([gObject getJustExitedRegion])
    {
        [self didExitRegion:region forObject:gObject];
        NSLog(@"%@",[@"didExitRegion " stringByAppendingString:[gObject getGeofenceName]]);
        [gObject setJustExitedRegion:NO];
        [self replaceObjectWithUpdate:gObject];
        [timer invalidate];
        [self.timers removeObjectForKey:[gObject getGeofenceName]];
        info = nil;
    }else
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        [self.timers removeObjectForKey:[gObject getGeofenceName]];
        NSLog(@"%@", [@"Cancelled Exit Of Region: " stringByAppendingString:[gObject getGeofenceName]]);
        info = nil;
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is this line -

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(checkBackOnExit:) userInfo:info repeats:NO];
```

You don't store the new `NSTimer` that is returned from `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` anywhere so as soon as the method exits it will be deallocated.  You need to add the NSTimer to a property.  As you can possibly have multiple timers running concurrently I would suggest an `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
@property (retain,nonatomic)  NSMutableDictionary *timers;
```

Initialise this wherever appropriate (such as `init`)

```
self.timers=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
```

then in `didExitRegion:`

```
[self.timers addObject:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0f target:self selector:@selector(checkBackOnExit:) userInfo:info repeats:NO] forKey:gObject.geoFenceName];
```

In `didEnterRegion:`

```
NSTimer *timer=(NSTimer *)[self.timers objectForKey:gObject.geoFenceName]
if (timer != nil) {
    [timer invalidate];
    [self.timers removeObjectForKey:gObject.geoFenceName];
}
```

And also in your `checkBackOnExit:` method

```
[timer invalidate];
[self.timers removeObjectForKey:gObject.geoFenceName];
```

Comment: I just implemented what you said and it completely makes a ton of sense, however, I went and tested and the new log is updated in my main question.

Comment: I added a NSLog to the Timer code to see if it is cancelled or if it proceeds with the exit, that is where the cancelled's come from.

Comment: Can you update your code in your question (at least the new `checkBackOnExit`)?  At first glance, though I am not sure if you need to do any checking in this method.  Because `didEnterRegion` will cancel any outstanding timer for that region, if the timer fires it means that you didn't get an "enter" within the time period, so you are "out".

Comment: Actually, no. A scheduled timer is retained by the runloop. You don't have a reference to it, so you can't invalidate it, but you don't need to retain it just to make it work.

Comment: This led me to the actual problem.  I was calling a repopulate on an Array after a successful connection, in that repopulate I was setting the justExitedRegion value to NO.  So if there were 2 exits relatively close together, the first exit would reset that value to NO on the second exit before the timer got executed causing it to fail to run.

Comment: From the log it seems that `getJustExitedRegion` is NO.  This is probably because the object in your dictionary is a reference to an object that is being updated elsewhere.  As I said in my previous comment, I am not sure why you are checking the boolean.  If the timer fires then the region was exited and not re-entered

Comment: @Paulw11 I have changed the code to get rid of the boolean and just have it working off of the timer.  The reason I kept that code is because I just changed previously to your answer above and didn't think about it.  After reviewing I noticed it was getting updated elsewhere and in my post above yours talks about how I found that.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there a way to do the same with the bgTask (background task)?  Since I might make multiple request for background time at the same time depending how fast I move from one region to the next I don't want to cancel the instance bgTask as it will cancel them all.  However, my app is throwing crash logs about it running to long in the background and I think that is because I am letting the bgTask expire each time and not actually cancelling it.  It doesn't seem I can create a NSMutableDictionary with background task associated to gObjects so any recommendations how to keep track?

Comment: You can create a wrapper object with properties for your NSTimer and background task ID and add that to the dictionary, or you could create a second NSMutableDictionary and add the bg task ID using the same key, but because the BGTask ID is really an NSUInteger you would have to wrap it in an NSNumber before you can add it to the dictionary